# Javascript to determine table width/height

Tags: javascript, html-table, width

I've got some JavaScript I'm trying to use to define my table width/height to make it fluid across different resolutions. It seems to work fine for the width but I can't get it to work for the height. It is setting the correct number into the correct variable, it's just not setting the tables height. Here's what I got..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;
 var tablewidth;
 var tableheight;
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined'){ //set's viewport width/height into respective variables
              viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
              viewportheight = window.innerHeight
         }else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
             && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
             'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0){
               viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
               viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
         }else{
               viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
               viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
         } 
 function asdf(){
 tablewidth = Math.round(viewportwidth/100*70);  //sets table width to 70% of viewport width
 tableheight = Math.round(tablewidth/100*74);    //sets table height to 74% of table width, this number is ambigous
 document.getElementById('poop').innerHTML = tableheight+', '+tablewidth+', viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight;
 document.getElementById('container').width = tablewidth;
 document.getElementById('container').height = tableheight;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="asdf();">
<span id="poop"></span>
    <table id="container" cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="" height="">
        <tr><td colspan="5"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="38%"></td>
            <td width="12%"></td>
            <td width="21%"></td>
            <td width="14%"></td>
            <td width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this may this work

```
    var width = document.getElementById('container').style.offsetWidth;
    var height = document.getElementById('container').style.offsetheight;
```

Comment: if Table don't have any style directly use ------------->var width = document.getElementById('TableID').offsetWidth;

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use CSS?

```
#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 74%;
}
```

Comment: good question. i know i seem like a crazy person doing it this way but there is an actual reason. it's just easier not to go into unnecessary detail.

Comment: Because today every day a new technology adds... actually we don't have free time to make a lot css media or import conditions with terrible aspect ratio codes that are not compatible with all browsers... at least i'm sure all devices have javascript enabled even in mobile and tablets.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, there was nothing wrong with the Javascript. I didn't realize you can't put the height attribute in the `<table>` element, it must go in the `<td>` element.

I confirm, in PhoneGap, a simple table with height=100% doesn't size to the screen dimension, in HTML, in CSS, inside or outside of a DIV, etc...

My solution inspire by this post: I have compute the height of the table via the body height and distribute in pixel to each  of my table the dimension.

    /* this code is documented before, works fine and is here just to complete the presentation */

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );


/* this is a Topcoat navigation bar and I get its height via offsetHeight of the surrounding <div> */
var hTopBar = document.getElementById("pgTopBar").offsetHeight; 

var sH = Math.floor((height - hTopBar) / 3);


document.getElementById("td1").height = sH;
document.getElementById("td2").height = sH;
document.getElementById("td3").height = sH;
document.getElementById("td4").height = sH;
document.getElementById("td5").height = sH;
document.getElementById("td6").height = sH;
```

In my case, 2 cells per row, 3 rows in the table, so the height is 33% of the required height of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The working javascript code is

```
//With small change, which you are missing
document.getElementById('container').style.width = tablewidth+"px";
document.getElementById('container').style.height = tableheight+"px";
```

You can check [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbNBw/1/)